# Is it safe to access different sub-arrays with different threads without syncing?

Tags: c++, arrays, pthreads, parallel-processing

If I have 10 threads, and an array of 10 sub-arrays, is it safe to have each thread do work on a different one of the sub-arrays?  i.e. thread[0] does stuff to array[0], thread[1] does stuff to array[1], etc.  Or is this not safe to do?  Does it make a difference if it's a vector or array (or any data set for that matter)?

Comment: How large are the objects in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a "mother-array" which contains 10 smaller arrays and each thread is accessing one of those arrays exclusively then nothing bad can happen. The size of the elements of those arrays does not matter.

If you use more complex structures instead of arrays, if reading does not change anything then you are safe too. However, if a simple read from the structure can modify it (e.g. something is cached, reorganised), having parallel threads accessing the mother-structure can be problematic.

Apart from that - I don't see any case when this could cause trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're safe. As long as none of the threads modifies a resource other threads access without guards or syncing you're safe. It doesn't matter if the memory addresses are very close to each other; proximity doesn't play a role. All that matters is whether there's sharing, and if so does any of the threads modify the shared resource.

Comment: I look at it this way: While an infinite number of people can look at a glass of water at once, only one person can drink from it.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: I just don't see how is this relevant here

Comment: Proximity doesn't play a role for correctness, but thanks to depth of modern memory hierarchies, can play a potentially huge role for performance. The effect is known as "false sharing". Quote from Herb Sutter: _"couple of lines to remove false sharing takes an algorithm from zero scaling to perfect scaling"_.

Comment: I wasn't sure if they'd both try to access the "super" array at the same time, if that would have bad consequences.

Comment: @yi_H Why not? It just means that you can read data from many threads (at the same time) but write data from only one.

Comment: I have a question on similar lines. What if each thread accesses one individual element of an array? There is only one array in this case. Will this cause a problem?

Comment: @noMAD: do you do inserts/delete?

Comment: @noMAD it's the same thing again: no sharing, no problem. Same array, yes, same computer too -- but the bits being read/written to aren't the same.

Comment: @noMAD: that could be a problem with complex data structures... you really should understand the basics so you can figure out all the consequences without asking. do you understand the concept of sharing? do you know how a vector is implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but beware of [false sharing](http://herbsutter.com/2009/05/15/effective-concurrency-eliminate-false-sharing/).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially yes - it is safe at the array level (but it may also depend - see below). However, if it were another structure, for example a tree or a doubly-linked list, then you may run into issues if you try to modify the structure since a change to one element may require changes to other elements as well which is not safe. But as long as you are only reading the data, you should be OK. One possible pitfall is if the array contains references or pointers. In this case it may happen that while you are accessing separate array entries, the are directly or indirectly referencing the same areas in memory. In that case, you must perform proper synchronization.

So in one word: if it's an array of int or another simple data type, you are completely safe. If it's not an array or the elements are not completely in-place but contain pointers or references, you should be careful.